# how to create multiple distribution in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, seaborn, distribution

i am trying to create multiple distribution charts depending on a city name. I tried this code but this is plotting everything in one chart. I want all these generated seperately with city name as a title.

```
  for x in regions['City_Name'].unique():
        sns.distplot(regions['sales'][regions['City_Name']==x])
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you look into [`sns.catplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) ?

Comment: No JohanC but i will have a look